# fragment error upon starting new activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have trouble in starting new activity within the fragment class. Everytime, I click the specified image button it will have an error stating that it is undefined from another class. This class is the holder of the said fragment activity.

Here is the code

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    if (container == null) {
          return null;
       }

    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_seat_plan, container, false);



    button1 = (ImageButton)rootView.findViewById(R.id.ImageButton1);


    return rootView;
}
```

Upon clicking the button

```
public void AssignAddress(View view){
    Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), AssignSeat.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

Here's the logcat

```
03-15 23:27:56.842: W/dalvikvm(23000): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40bdc438)03-15 23:27:56.852: E/AndroidRuntime(23000): FATAL EXCEPTION: main03-15 23:27:56.852: E/AndroidRuntime(23000): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method AssignAddress(View) in the activity class com.example.mcr.InstructorMenu for onClick handler on view class android.widget.ImageButton with id 'ImageButton1'
```

Answer (score 0):

First, show more code; secondly, the code is complaining about the non-existent method. Here is what might help you:

In your fragment, you need to implement the click listener for your button (which MUST be in the fragment layout as well).

Inside the click method, you should then start the new activity - you don't even need a method for that.

Again, more code of your activity structure might help and the rest of your fragment.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to hook the AssignAddress(View view) method from the xml like this `android:onClick="AssignAddress"`
which will not work because after the user clicks this button the compiler will try to find the method in the activity that the fragment resides in but not in the fragment where you have declared the method. So You must remove this from the xml and change to the following

```
public class YourFragment extends Fragment implements
    OnClickListener {

   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {

   if (container == null) {
      return null;
    }

    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_seat_plan, container, false);



    button1 = (ImageButton)rootView.findViewById(R.id.ImageButton1);
    button1.setOnClickListener(this);


    return rootView;
}
////your other codes 
///////

//the OnClickListener 
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent i=null;
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.ImageButton1:
        i= new Intent(getActivity(), AssignSeat.class);
        startActivity(i);
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
}

}
```